# Is there a way to automatically restart Apache on Mac OS X if it crashes?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, macports, launchd

I've installed Apache using [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts). It crashes every once in a while, and I need to manually restart it.

Is there a way to get Apache to automatically restart if it dies for some reason? Perhaps using [`launchd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) somehow?

Comment: Have you considered posting a question about stopping Apache from crashing? It really shouldn't ever crash. Perhaps there are some configuration details some log entries or some known circumstances that you could describe.

Comment: I second that idea, maybe you want to fix the issue that causes Apache to crash or be more specific about any error logs.

Comment: Do you have a little brother? Little brothers are good for automated tasks :D

Comment: The current Macports version is apparently 1.3.41, the current version is 2.2.17, Snow's Apache is 2.2.15

Comment: @tobylane There are two branches of the Apache web server which have been developed in parallel for years. MacPorts offers both 1.x as `apache` and 2.x as `apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `launchd` to start Apache, and make Apache run in the foreground so `launchd` can monitor it and restart it if it crashes. Since the system includes a `launchd` item (`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`) to start the built-in version of Apache, I'd just copy that to `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, change the filename and Label so `launchd` won't get them confused, remove the Disabled key, and change `ProgramArguments` to point to the MacPorts version of Apache. Be sure to keep the `-D` and `FOREGROUND` arguments to `httpd`, or it'll daemonize itself and `launchd` will start another instance and nothing useful will get done.

(And do follow @RedGrittyBrick's advice about finding the actual cause of the crash. While `launchd` is the "right" way to start a daemon like Apache on Mac OS X, it's just a band-aid for whatever problem Apache is having.)